# .NET Core 2.1 Azure AD B2C Web and API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

It is easy to create an Azure AD B2C Web or API App out of the box using `VS 2017 15.7.2+`.

So I created a solution that has both, but I am trying to get the access token from the Web App and use it to call the API and I cannot find a way.

I tried option 1 (**doesn't work**):

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenCacheAsync()
{
    string authority = $"{AzureAdOptions.Instance}{AzureAdOptions.ClientId}/{AzureAdOptions.SignUpSignInPolicyId}/";
    string clientId = AzureAdOptions.ClientId;
    Uri redirectUri = new Uri("https://localhost:12345/");
    string resource = targetApplicationID;
    AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    try
    {
        result = await ac.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId);
    }
    catch (AdalException adalException)
    {
        if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently
            || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.InteractionRequired)
        {
            result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectUri,
                                                new PlatformParameters()); //PromptBehavior.Auto
        }
    }
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

And I Got:

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

I tried option 2 (**doesn't work**), MSAL (Microsoft.Identity.Client):

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenCacheAsync() {
    string authority = $"{AzureAdOptions.Instance}{AzureAdOptions.ClientId}/{AzureAdOptions.SignUpSignInPolicyId}/";
    PublicClientApplication myApp = new PublicClientApplication(AzureAdOptions.ClientId, authority);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await myApp.AcquireTokenAsync(
        new[] { $"{ApiScopeUrl}/read", $"{ApiScopeUrl}/write" }
        ,
        myApp.Users.FirstOrDefault()
        ,
        UIBehavior.ForceLogin
        ,null,null
        ,authority
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

And I Got:

```
System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'
```

I also tried to adapt the code from Azure samples such as https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi (Framework 4.5.1) or https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore (Core 2.0 and OpenID, no B2C) and fail.

This https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp also mention to implement `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived`, but Core 2.1 seems to has this implemented with `AddAzureADB2C` (black-boxed). The documentation on this new library seems to be missing or in progress because I can't find it.

I want to know, how to get the Access Token using built-in features in .NET Core 2.1?

I believe if I know how to implement `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived`, I will be one step closer to find the answer. Here the code source and ticket that I created relates to this: https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/issues/21

Comment: I have a similiar or the same issue. Samples and docs are for 1.1 or 2.0 and the B2C is setup differently in the new .Net Core 2.1. I can't get a token using Postman either. Have you tried Postman to test the B2C setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Hi @Jaider. See [Unable to access a WebApi from a MVC Web app where both are secured by Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917054/unable-to-access-a-webapi-from-a-mvc-web-app-where-both-are-secured-by-azure-ad).